# Trying to retrieve Facebook events returns an empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve all the events from a public page and I'm just getting an empty array. It works with the feed and I've tried this being logged in and looking into my profile and it gets the events, so I don't really get why is not working with a public page.

Here is my code. Any thoughs?

```
session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'base_facebook.php';
require_once 'facebook.php';

use base_facebook;
use Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\AccessToken;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '{app_id}',
    'secret' => '{app_secret}',
    "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/fb/src/acme/app/facebookpoc.php",
    'cookie' => true ));

// Graph API to request to EVENTS
    $pageevents = $facebook->api("/" . "nike" . "/events?fields=name,description,privacy,end_time,location");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $pageevents );
    echo "</pre>";

    // Loop for events
    foreach($pageevents['data'] as $event) {
        // Open up an fb-event div
        echo "<div class=\"fb-event\">";

        // Post start time of the event and its data
        echo "<h2>The event starts on: " . date("jS M, Y", (strtotime($event['start_time']))) . "</h2>";
        echo "<p> Name of the event: " . $event['name'] . "</p>";

        if (isset($event['description']))   //Check if the event has a description concreted
        {
            echo "<p> Description of the event: " . $event['description'] . "</p>";
        }
        else echo "<p> Event has no description concreted </p>";

        if (isset($event['location']))  //Check if the event has a location concreted
        {
            echo "<p> Location of the event: " . $event['location'] . "</p>";
        }
        else echo "<p> The event has no location concreted </p>";

        if (isset($event['end_time']))  //Check if the event has ending time
        {
            echo "<p> The event ends at: " . date("jS M, Y", (strtotime($event['end_time']))) . "</p>";
        }
        else echo "<p> The ending time of the event hasn't been concreted </p>";

        if($event['privacy'] != "OPEN") // Check the current privacy of the event
        {
            echo "<p> <strong>The event is not fully public!! </p> </strong>";
        }
        else echo "<p> The event is <strong>fully public!</strong> </p>";

        // Close fb-event div
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

And it outputs:

> Array
>   (
>       [data] => Array
>           (
>           )
>   )

Thanks in advance, but I don't really get why is this happening...

Comment: The `nike` page doesn't have any current events. Why don't you try a page that does have a upcoming event and see if your code works then.

Comment: The point is that I don't get any kind of event (not even the "passed" ones trying with any other pages. Any ideas? Thanks by the way

Comment: Did you find a solution??